# Can use Angular js in material design? instead of using Angular material design

Tags: angularjs, material-design

My project was developed by normal jquery with material design. But, now I am implementing AngularJs in my project. Material design does not support angular js(won't bind to scope object). My friend suggest me to use angular material design. My customer don't like angular material design UI, He wants material design UI. 
**Any solution to use MaterialDesign with angular instead of AngularMaterialDesign**

Comment: What do you mean by "My customer don't like angular material design UI, He wants material design UI" ? Angular material is just an angular wrapper for the material design specs. I don't see any visual difference between the two.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I saw the element in AngularDesignMaterial and DesignMaterial. Both are different UI.

Answer (score 1):

[Angular.js](https://angularjs.org/) is a MVC framework, [Material Design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) is just a design guide made by Google.

If you want to have your angular frontend look like Google's material design, you can either include the [CSS only](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite) or use something like [Angular material lite](https://github.com/jadjoubran/angular-material-design-lite), which wraps angular with material design.

There is no need for you to include Angular.js if you want to have material design or the other way, include material design together with angular, both of them can be used separatly.

Comment: For a example, both datepicker in material design and datepicker in angular material design are differenent UI. I want datepicker in material design with angular js